# RDP outside of home network

Tags: rdp

I'm leaving for the rest of year soon, and I'd like to be able to remote desktop from my ubuntu into both a popos and a windows 10 machine using remmina which is installed on both linux computers. I connect to windows through the remote desktop thats built in. I have everything working fine on my home network, but I'm having a hard time finding specifics about how to do it outside of the house. Specifically, I don't see what I'm supposed to log into/what address once I'm off my home network since my local network ip wont work. What do I do and is there a way to check to see it works outside of my network before I leave?

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, I don't see what I'm supposed to log into/what address once I'm off my home network since my local network ip wont work

There are two ways to do that: a **terribly insecure way** and a more secure way.

The **terribly insecure way** is to simply provide a public address to your machines using NAT/port forwarding on your router. This means *everybody* on the Internet can reach your computers and attempt to log in via RDP. If you're thinking "who even knows about me or my RDP?" think twice: there are a lot of bots scanning the Internet for all kinds of stuff, and exposed RDP is one of the most common thing they're looking for. If you're not convinced yet, here are some links, but anyway, **please don't just expose RDP to the Internet** unless you're building a honeypot (a system designed to attract hackers):

- https://www.cloudflare.com/en-us/learning/access-management/rdp-security-risks/
- https://research.nccgroup.com/2021/10/21/detecting-and-protecting-when-remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-is-open-to-the-internet/
- https://www.csoonline.com/article/3542895/attacks-against-internet-exposed-rdp-servers-surging-during-covid-19-pandemic.html

The more secure way is setting up a VPN. In this way, you can access your entire private network from the Internet as if you were at home, but only after being properly authenticated.

Oh, did I mention exposing RDP to the Internet is terribly insecure?